# How to change extended ID option value of the marker in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Im adding a new marker with "uniqueID" option like this:

```
var mp = new L.Marker([10, 20],{uniqueID: id}).addTo(map);
```

And it works well: I can identify markers by this option value.
But I don't know how to change this value dynamically, I tried this:

```
mp.properties.uniqueID = newID;
```

And it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Just `mp.options.uniqueID = newValue`

Comment: Thanks for greetings.  I tried that too and it didnt work.

Comment: Oh i finnaly find where i messed up and it has nothing to do with variable assignment. 
```
mp.options.uniqueID = newValue
```
This works well. Thanks.